# How to enable and disable log4Net log levels?

Tags: log4net, app-config

I am trying to setup the log4net configuration in my Dot Net Core C# library. I have configured the following log levels. But I want to enable and disable the log levels independently.

```
   <root>
        <level value="Info" /> 
        <level value="Warn" />
        <level value="Error" />
        <level value="Fatal" />
        <level value="Debug" />

        <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
   </root>
```

For example, how can I disable and enable the Debug flag by setting it to true or false?
Something like

```
 <level value="Debug"  Enable = "True"/>
```

I think there is some settings, but I don't remember. Thanks for your help to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to apply a [`LevelMatchFilter`](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/log4net-1.2.11/release/sdk/log4net.Filter.LevelMatchFilter.html) on the appender, which filters on the exact match of the specified level. You can combine multiple filters in case you want to log more than 1 specific level.
Note that you have to end with a [`DenyAllFilter`](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/log4net-1.2.11/release/sdk/log4net.Filter.DenyAllFilter.html) to block the other levels.

An example, given these log statements

```
logger.Debug("Debug");
logger.Info("Info");
logger.Warn("Warn");
logger.Error("Error");
logger.Fatal("Fatal");
```

When you apply the configuration below, only the message `Debug` will be logged.

```
<log4net>
    <appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
        <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelMatchFilter">
            <levelToMatch value="DEBUG" />
        </filter>
        <filter type="log4net.Filter.DenyAllFilter" />
        
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%message%newline" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
        <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
    </root>
</log4net>
```

When you want to log 2 levels, e.g. only error and info, then you combine the filters as shown here.
The log output will be `Info` and `Error`.

```
<log4net>
    <appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
        <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelMatchFilter">
            <levelToMatch value="ERROR" />
        </filter>
        <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelMatchFilter">
            <levelToMatch value="INFO" />
        </filter>
        <filter type="log4net.Filter.DenyAllFilter" />
        
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%message%newline" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
        <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
    </root>
</log4net>
```

Answer (score 0):

> But I want to enable and disable the log levels independently.

You can't.

The levels are not independent but ordered as follows

> ```
> ALL
> DEBUG
> INFO
> WARN
> ERROR
> FATAL
> OFF
> ```

So when you set your logging level you automatically include messages for that level **and** all lower levels.

E.g. If you set your level to Debug you also get Info,Warn, Error and Fatal messages and if your set your level to Info, you also get Warn, Error and Fatal messages etc